# Angularjs send value to database when leaving input field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

Been looking around but i can't seem to find any good resources.
Got an application where i want to update the data in the database once the user leaves the textbox/area etc., figured i could probably do this with the ngfocus event but i would also need to get which field has triggered the update.

Not sure on how to proceed, might not event be the best thing to use ngfocus. Perhaps creating a new directive or maybe extending ngfocus if possible. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I would create a new directive that uses `.blur` - attach it to your input element and then call your service from that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [ngBlur](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) instead.

HTML:

```
<input ng-blur='sendData()' />
```

Just make sure your controller exposes a `sendData` method on the scope.